# does c++ unordered_set's iterator begin() always point to the same element

Tags: c++

Since `unordered_set<int>  nums` does NOT sort the elements, is `*nums.begin()` always the same? Or it changes sometime (although rarely) when we access it again?

Comment: To clarify, you mean *without* modifying the set between calls, right? i.e. you're asking whether `*nums.begin() == *nums.begin()` is always true, right?

Comment: without modifying. yes. I mean in each time of access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no guarantees about the ordering *after each mutation* (insertion, deletion). But the ordering is consistent for a given internal state. So repeated calls to `begin()` will return the same element, only until you modify the container. After that point, `begin()` may return any element.

The [`unordered_set<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) class is implemented thus:

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets. Which bucket an element is placed into depends entirely on the hash of its value. This allows fast access to individual elements, since once a hash is computed, it refers to the exact bucket the element is placed into.

So the first element returned by `begin()` will depend on the hashes of other elements in the container, as that determines which bucket they are allocated into. Accordingly, each time the container is modified, the "first" element (actually the iteration order) may change. But between mutations, the elements' hashes do not change, thus the ordering will be *consistent*.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation regarding this. thanks.

Comment: I've added a link to the C++ library reference, and expanded the explanation, so hopefully this will be clearer. If you want to deep dive into the standard, start in Section 23.2.5 [unord_req].